# Pass argument to data.table aggregation function

Tags: r, data.table

I have a function that calculates a weighted mean of a variable and groups it by time period using the `data.table` aggregation syntax. However, I want to provide the name of the weighting column programmatically. Is there a way to accomplish this while still using the traditional `data.table` syntax? The function `wtmean1` below demonstrates the idea of what I want to do (but it produces an error). The function `wtmean2` works and is inspired by the `data.table` FAQ, but it's more cumbersome to pass in the whole expression, and it's not possible to extract out the name of the weighting column within the function, which might be needed. Is there a way to get `wtmean1` to work, where the only argument that I pass in is the name of the weighting column in a string?

```
wtmean1 <- function(dt1, weight) {
  dt1[,weighted.mean(x, weight), by=timeperiod]
}

wtmean2 <- function(dt1, expr) {
  dt1[,eval(substitute(expr)), by=timeperiod]
}

mydata <- data.table(x=1:10, timeperiod=rep(1:2,5), wt1=rnorm(10), wt2=rnorm(10))
wtmean1(mydata, "wt1") # ERROR
wtmean2(mydata, weighted.mean(x, wt2))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `get`:

```
wtmean1 <- function(dt1, weight) {
  dt1[,weighted.mean(x, get(weight)), by=timeperiod]
}
```

With your sample data:

```
> set.seed(1)
> mydata <- data.table(x=1:10, timeperiod=rep(1:2,5), wt1=rnorm(10), wt2=rnorm(10))
> wtmean1(mydata, "wt1")
   timeperiod          V1
1:          1 -102.476925
2:          2    3.362326
```

Comment: great! I believe this is the first time I have to use get. It would be great to understand more how this works. Perhaps you can expand the answer a bit.