# Why does `DT[, .(get(x))]` rename x? And how do I use the original name?

Tags: r, function, data.table, subset

As documented [here](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#passing-datatable-column-names-as-function-arguments) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196994/pass-argument-to-data-table-aggregation-function?rq=1) you can use `get()` in a function to pull the column from a data.table from the function arguments to use in the process.

Data.table is neat because it allows you to subset columns within it's j argument, and to also serve lists to it's by and keyby arguments.

R is cool because you can write custom functions easily. However, trying to do all of the above is hard (for me).

I would like to write a custom function to return a subset of columns, where some of the columns are specified by the arguments of the custom function. It's important that these retain their original name when the data.table is returned.

The get approach seems to supply the correct values, however it renames the columns to something meaningless outside of the function (`Vx`, or something),

```
library(data.table)

irisDT <- data.table(iris)

getCol <- function(DT = irisDT, col = "Sepal.Width"){
    DT[, .(get(col), Sepal.Length)]
}

getCol()

getCol(col = "Petal.Width")
```

An alternative approach using `darse(substitute(x))` has also been suggested. Applying it (best I can) here also doesn't seem to work.

```
getCol2 <- function(DT = irisDT, col = Sepal.Width){
    col2 = deparse(substitute(col))
    DT[, .(col2, Sepal.Length)]
}

getCol2()

getCol2(col = Petal.Width)
```

How can I write a function that returns a column within a data.table via a custom function, that also allows me to supply the selected column to a list of column names in data.table, without changing the column name?

Comment: "how do I use the original name?" `DT[,.SD, .SDcols=x]` or `DT[,x,with=FALSE]` as far as "why?", well, you did not give it a name in terms of the R syntax, so why should it have one? You can maybe `setNames(get(x), x)` if that's what you're after...

Comment: Indeed have a look at DT[,vector_of_columns_names, with=FALSE]

Comment: Thanks @Frank, however, the use case I have in mind is minorly more complex than the mwe, making use of .SD less straight forward (for me), it is a good suggestion though. I will attempt to apply a more .SD friendly process and come back to this question on completion.